# Weird behavior of comparison operator JavaScript when using empty array

Tags: javascript

Can you explain this weird JavaScript behavior?

First :

```
[] === []  false
[] ==  []  false
```

Why false? The object are identical, thus it should return true.

Second :

```
 [] !== []  true
 [] !=  []  true
```

Again, why true? the objects are identical.

Comment: you can compare values not objects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're not identical. [Object identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_(object-oriented_programming)) is defined by both operands pointing to the same instance.

```
var a = [],
    b = [];
a == b; // false
a == a; // true
```

Two literals always evaluate to two different instances, which are not considered equal. If you are looking for structural equivalence, see [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/comparing-two-arrays-in-javascript).

Answer (score 5):

Objects are **not** identical. In this case you compare the references to the objects. Easily speaking you compare the addresses in memory where these objects are located. This rule doesn't relate to primitives where you compare the actual values.